# Importing MSSQL database backup to MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server, windows, macos, ssms

Due to a change in jobs, I've recently had to move over to mac, but before I left, I made a backup of all my local MSSQL databases containing a lot of important work. 
Is there any way I can bring these into MySQL workbench, without the use of a windows PC to alter the backups?

Comment: Are these databases even yours to possess? If they came from your previous place of employment, they may have an ownership claim on them, or even worse they may contain proprietary data that you aren't allowed to possess now that you aren't employed there anymore.

Comment: Very good question. They were all publicly available data from the office of national statistics. I'd just spent the time compiling multiple csv's into usable tables.

Comment: From an ownership perspective, you may be better off rebuilding the database from scratch in MySQL at home then. That way you're not at risk of the company claiming you took work that you'd done for them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. SQL Server backups can only be restored to an instance of SQL Server. On-disk structures, data types, stored procedures, functions, etc. all have differences.

The reverse is true as well - you can't "import" a MySQL backup into SQL Server.

You will need to restore your SQL Server backup into an instance of SQL Server, then export the data from SQL Server into MySQL. The Import/Export Wizard in SSMS may be able to help you if you have the appropriate drivers, otherwise you'll be writing your own ETL process in your language/environment of choice. You'll probably want to create your table schema in MySQL first, to ensure the appropriate data types are used. Programmable features (stored procs, UDFs, triggers, etc.) will need to be re-implemented using the proper dialect of SQL for MySQL as it doesn't speak T-SQL.